# compare two files (fasta and txt), if match then prefix fasta header with value from txt file

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I'd like to change my FASTA headers based on information from a reference text file. So say I have two files:

file1.txt (reference, tab-delimited)

```
chr1:100-1000(+)   ORF1_ORF2_
chr2:30-400(-)     ORF2_
chr3:50-4500(+)
chr4:60-800(-)     ORF1_
```

file2.fasta

```
>chr1:100-1000(+)
TTTTGAGAGGACTTCTCTGAGAGCTATGCTAGTCATCGAGGGGAAA
>chr2:30-400(-)
GGGGGGAGAGAGATCTCTGAGCTAGTCATCGTAGCTAGTCATGGGG
>chr3:50-4500(+)
ATGCGCGAGCGAGCGCGACGATCATCGTAGCTACAAAAAAAAAAAG
>chr4:60-800(-)
AGTCTAGCTATCGTAGCTGATCGTAGCTAGCTGATCGTAGCTAGTC
```

I want to use $1 from file1.txt to identify the corresponding header in file2.fasta. If there is a match, prefix the current header with $2 from file1.txt. So the desired output would be:

output.fasta

```
>ORF1_ORF2_chr1:100-1000(+)
TTTTGAGAGGACTTCTCTGAGAGCTATGCTAGTCATCGAGGGGAAA
>ORF2_chr2:30-400(-)
GGGGGGAGAGAGATCTCTGAGCTAGTCATCGTAGCTAGTCATGGGG
>chr3:50-4500(+)
ATGCGCGAGCGAGCGCGACGATCATCGTAGCTACAAAAAAAAAAAG
>ORF1_chr4:60-800(-)
AGTCTAGCTATCGTAGCTGATCGTAGCTAGCTGATCGTAGCTAGTC
```

I've used awk in the past to compare columns from two files, but I'm stumped as to how to compare a text file to a fasta file (where there are headers and sequences instead of columns). Any help would be great!

Comment: why does this have the python and bash tags? please remove unrelated tags.

Comment: Oh come on. I didn't mention the sed tag, but **you are not using sed**. Please apply brain and common courtesy.

Comment: I didn't mean to restrict the question to only awk solutions (similar questions seem to have been solved with sed etc, hence the flag).

Comment: ^^ Agreed. I just cooked up the answer in hurry. Deleted the comment because it suggested a bad practice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{m[">"$1]=$2;next} {sub(/^>/,"&"m[$0])} 1' file1 file2
>ORF1_ORF2_chr1:100-1000(+)
TTTTGAGAGGACTTCTCTGAGAGCTATGCTAGTCATCGAGGGGAAA
>ORF2_chr2:30-400(-)
GGGGGGAGAGAGATCTCTGAGCTAGTCATCGTAGCTAGTCATGGGG
>chr3:50-4500(+)
ATGCGCGAGCGAGCGCGACGATCATCGTAGCTACAAAAAAAAAAAG
>ORF1_chr4:60-800(-)
AGTCTAGCTATCGTAGCTGATCGTAGCTAGCTGATCGTAGCTAGTC
```

The above assumes $2 in file1 cannot contain an `&`.

Comment: This is almost perfect except that it puts the value (ORF1_ etc) before the '>', corrupting the header. I'm playing with it now to try to change that (without post-processing it)

Comment: I modified it to put it after the `>`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) If you don't mind another stupid question, what is the `^` for, in `sub(/^>/`? I tried it without that (e.g. just `/>/`) and it seems to do the same thing

Comment: `^` is the regexp start-of-string metacharacter. In this case, since the string in question is a whole line, it anchors the `>` regexp to the start of the line. If that's the only place `>` can occur then you don't need it. The equivalent end-of-string metacharacter is `$`, often used for end-of-line matching, especially in sed and grep since they are line-oriented.